# Detecting content type of a file based on its resource

Tags: php, mime-types

I'm attempting to determine the content type of a file based on its resource. Something along these lines:

```
$resource = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');

$contentType = getContentTypeFromResource($resource);
```

I know of a way to get the content type of a file in PHP based on its location:

```
// Method 1
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$contentType = finfo_file($finfo, '/path/to/file');
```

Unfortunately for reasons too lengthy to go into detail here, it would be much easier for me to determine this from a resource.

Is this possible?

Comment: in short, can't be done

Comment: @Dagon, is it true that it can't be done even if (in my case) I know that the `$resource` is an image?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda late but couldn't we use [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) for this?

something like:

```
$encoded = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
$resource = base64_decode($encoded);
$tmp = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmp, $resource);
rewind($tmp);
echo mime_content_type($tmp);
fclose($tmp);
```

seems to work for me at least.